# Не получается получить путь к файлу через Uri

Tags: java

пытаюсь получить путь к файлу через uri с помощью метода getPath(), но при проверке файла, его не находит.
Путь такой:

> /document/raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/samp.pdf

код:

```
uploadFilePath = Uri_for_load_pdf.getPath();
sourceFile = new File(uploadFilePath );
```

Comment: Что пишет ? покажите ошибку.

Comment: @НиколайГнап, ошибки нет, я проверяю методом isFile()

Comment: может это 2 пути склеены